# How do I use a self signed certificate for a HTTPS Node.js server?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I have started writing a wrapper for an API which requires all requests to be over HTTPS. Instead of making requests to the actual API while I am developing and testing it I would like to run my own server locally which mocks the responses.

I am confused about how to generate the certificates I need to create a HTTPS server and send requests to it.

My server looks something like this:

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('OK\n');
}).listen(8000);
```

The pem files were generated with:

```
openssl genrsa 1024 > key.pem
openssl req -x509 -new -key key.pem > cert.pem
```

And a request looks something like this:

```
var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8000,
  path: '/api/v1/test'
};

https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.pipe(process.stdout);
}).end();
```

With this setup I get `Error: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT`, so I think I need to add a `ca` option for the request.

So my question is how should I generate the following:

1. The server `key`?
2. The server `cert`?
3. The `ca` for the request?

I have read a few things about generating self signed certificates with openssl, but can't seem to wrap my head around it and figure out which keys and certificates to use where in my node code.

**Update**

The API provides a CA certificate to use instead of the defaults. The following code works using their certificate and this is what I want to reproduce locally.

```
var ca = fs.readFileSync('./certificate.pem');

var options = {
  host: 'example.com',
  path: '/api/v1/test',
  ca: ca
};
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.pipe(process.stdout);
}).end();
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

#### Update (Nov 2018): Do you *need* self-signed certs?

Or would real certificates get the job done better? Have you considered any of these?

- Let's Encrypt via [Greenlock.js](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js)
- Let's Encrypt via https://greenlock.domains
- Localhost relay service such as https://telebit.cloud

*(Note: Let's Encrypt can also issue certificates to private networks)*

## ScreenCast

https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-create-a-csr-for-https-tls-ssl-rsa-pems/

## Full, Working example

- creates certificates
- runs node.js server
- no warnings or errors in node.js client
- no warnings or errors in cURL

https://github.com/coolaj86/nodejs-self-signed-certificate-example

Using `localhost.greenlock.domains` as an example (it points to 127.0.0.1):

### server.js

```
'use strict';

var https = require('https')
  , port = process.argv[2] || 8043
  , fs = require('fs')
  , path = require('path')
  , server
  , options
  ;

require('ssl-root-cas')
  .inject()
  .addFile(path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'my-private-root-ca.cert.pem'))
  ;

options = {
  // this is ONLY the PRIVATE KEY
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'privkey.pem'))
  // You DO NOT specify `ca`, that's only for peer authentication
//, ca: [ fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'my-private-root-ca.cert.pem'))]
  // This should contain both cert.pem AND chain.pem (in that order) 
, cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'fullchain.pem'))
};


function app(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello, encrypted world!');
}

server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function () {
  port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Listening on https://127.0.0.1:' + port);
  console.log('Listening on https://' + server.address().address + ':' + port);
  console.log('Listening on https://localhost.greenlock.domains:' + port);
});
```

### client.js

```
'use strict';

var https = require('https')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , path = require('path')
  , ca = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'my-private-root-ca.cert.pem'))
  , port = process.argv[2] || 8043
  , hostname = process.argv[3] || 'localhost.greenlock.domains'
  ;

var options = {
  host: hostname
, port: port
, path: '/'
, ca: ca
};
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.pipe(process.stdout);
}).end();
```

And the script that makes the certificate files:

### make-certs.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
FQDN=$1

# make directories to work from
mkdir -p server/ client/ all/

# Create your very own Root Certificate Authority
openssl genrsa \
  -out all/my-private-root-ca.privkey.pem \
  2048

# Self-sign your Root Certificate Authority
# Since this is private, the details can be as bogus as you like
openssl req \
  -x509 \
  -new \
  -nodes \
  -key all/my-private-root-ca.privkey.pem \
  -days 1024 \
  -out all/my-private-root-ca.cert.pem \
  -subj "/C=US/ST=Utah/L=Provo/O=ACME Signing Authority Inc/CN=example.com"

# Create a Device Certificate for each domain,
# such as example.com, *.example.com, awesome.example.com
# NOTE: You MUST match CN to the domain name or ip address you want to use
openssl genrsa \
  -out all/privkey.pem \
  2048

# Create a request from your Device, which your Root CA will sign
openssl req -new \
  -key all/privkey.pem \
  -out all/csr.pem \
  -subj "/C=US/ST=Utah/L=Provo/O=ACME Tech Inc/CN=${FQDN}"

# Sign the request from Device with your Root CA
openssl x509 \
  -req -in all/csr.pem \
  -CA all/my-private-root-ca.cert.pem \
  -CAkey all/my-private-root-ca.privkey.pem \
  -CAcreateserial \
  -out all/cert.pem \
  -days 500

# Put things in their proper place
rsync -a all/{privkey,cert}.pem server/
cat all/cert.pem > server/fullchain.pem         # we have no intermediates in this case
rsync -a all/my-private-root-ca.cert.pem server/
rsync -a all/my-private-root-ca.cert.pem client/

# create DER format crt for iOS Mobile Safari, etc
openssl x509 -outform der -in all/my-private-root-ca.cert.pem -out client/my-private-root-ca.crt
```

For example:

```
bash make-certs.sh 'localhost.greenlock.domains'
```

Hopefully this puts the nail in the coffin on this one.

And some more explanation: https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas/wiki/Painless-Self-Signed-Certificates-in-node.js

## Install private cert on iOS Mobile Safari

You need to create a copy of the root ca certificate a DER format with a .crt extension:

```
# create DER format crt for iOS Mobile Safari, etc
openssl x509 -outform der -in all/my-private-root-ca.cert.pem -out client/my-private-root-ca.crt
```

Then you can simply serve that file with your webserver. When you click the link you should be asked if you want to install the certificate.

For an example of how this works you can try installing MIT's Certificate Authority: https://ca.mit.edu/mitca.crt

## Related Examples

- https://github.com/coolaj86/nodejs-ssl-example
- https://github.com/coolaj86/nodejs-ssl-trusted-peer-example
- https://github.com/coolaj86/node-ssl-root-cas
- https://github.com/coolaj86/nodejs-https-sni-vhost-example

  - (Multiple vhosts with SSL on the same server)
- https://telebit.cloud

  - (get REAL SSL certs you can use TODAY for testing on localhost)

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to be enough. Add in websockets then try to access from Safari. Even if I serve the cert I'll get a message asking if I want to install the cert but after installing it secure websockets fail. Have you had any luck with self-signed certs + safari iOS?

Comment: @gman: If you want to use it in safari you need to add your root ca. I updated the tutorial with an iOS section.

Comment: If you need to get the CA pem for the server you are calling use this command (its the last certificate in the output) ```openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.example.com:443 </dev/null```

Comment: Your answer is worth an article, extremely useful!

Comment: @coolaj86 you mentioned "Let's Encrypt can also issue certificates to private networks" - do you have a link to any relevant documentation here?

Comment: @GershomMaes You just need to use DNS validation. As long as the DNS can be publicly validated it's fine for the IP address to be private. So you could have mylaptop.internal.company.com.

Answer (score 13):

Try adding this to your request options

```
var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8000,
  path: '/api/v1/test',
  // These next three lines
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  requestCert: true,
  agent: false
};
```

Comment: This works, perfect solution for local development, but probably need to turn off when pushing to production.

Answer (score 3):

Your key generation looks okay. You shouldn't need a ca because you aren't rejecting unsigned requests.

Add .toString() to the end of your readFileSync methods so that you are actually passing a string, not a file object.

Comment: In recent version of Node the rejectUnauthorized option is set to true by default so the requests are being rejected. The toString is unnecessary because readFileSync returns a Buffer when no encoding is specified, and the ca, cert and key options accept a Buffer or String.

Comment: So does this mean you made reject unsigned requests false and it was working?

Comment: Yes, I can do that but it's not what I want. The API I am using has provided me with a CA certificate that I can use for authorization, and I want to mirror this setup locally.

Answer (score 3):

This procedure allows you to create both a certificate authority & a certificate :

1. grab this `ca.cnf` file to use as a configuration shortcut :

   `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anders94/https-authorized-clients/master/keys/ca.cnf`

---

2. create a new certificate authority using this configuration :

   `openssl req -new -x509 -days 9999 -config ca.cnf -keyout ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem`

---

3. now that we have our certificate authority in `ca-key.pem` and `ca-cert.pem`, let's generate a private key for the server :

   `openssl genrsa -out key.pem 4096`

---

4. grab this `server.cnf` file to use as a configuration shortcut :

   `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anders94/https-authorized-clients/master/keys/server.cnf`

---

5. generate the certificate signing request using this configuration :

   `openssl req -new -config server.cnf -key key.pem -out csr.pem`

---

6. sign the request :

   `openssl x509 -req -extfile server.cnf -days 999 -passin "pass:password" -in csr.pem -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out cert.pem`

I found this procedure [**here**](http://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js/), along with more information on how to use these certificates.

Comment: Can I use this approach in production?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
  agent: false,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
```

Comment: This is no different to what @Loourr suggested.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the self-signed cert[s], you tell Node.js to *use* it with the Environment variable: NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS

Copy [cat] all the generated *.cert.pem files to a single file.
I put it the directory with all the keys & certs:

```
> (cd $keys; cat *.cert.pem > node_extra_ca_certs)
```

Tell node where to find them:

```
> export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=$keys/node_extra_ca_certs
```

Now, when you run node, it will accept your private certs as valid.