# OkHttp javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname domain.com not verified

Tags: java, android, ssl, okhttp

I've been trying for days to get this working. I'm trying to connect to my server over **https** with a self signed certificate. I don't think there is any pages or examples that I haven't read by now.

What I have done:

1. Created bks keystore by following this tutorial: http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html

It uses `openssl s_client -connect domain.com:443` to get the certificate from the server. Then creates a bks keystore using bouncy castle.

2. Reading created keystore from raw folder adding it to sslfactory and and then to OkHttpClient. Like this:

   ```
   public ApiService() {
       mClient = new OkHttpClient();
       mClient.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       mClient.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       mClient.setCache(getCache());
       mClient.setCertificatePinner(getPinnedCerts());
       mClient.setSslSocketFactory(getSSL());
   }

   protected SSLSocketFactory getSSL() {
       try {
           KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
           InputStream in = Beadict.getAppContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mytruststore);
           trusted.load(in, "pwd".toCharArray());
           SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
           TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
           trustManagerFactory.init(trusted);
           sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
           return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
       } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }

   public CertificatePinner getPinnedCerts() {
       return new CertificatePinner.Builder()
               .add("domain.com", "sha1/theSha=")
               .build();
   }
   ```
3. This for some reason this always generates a `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` with or without the keystore. And with or without the `CertificatePinner`.

   ```
   javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname domain.com not verified: 0         
    W/System.err﹕ certificate: sha1/theSha=
    W/System.err﹕ DN: 1.2.840.113549.1.9.1=#1610696e666f40626561646963742e636f6d,CN=http://domain.com,OU=development,O=domain,L=Valencia,ST=Valencia,C=ES
    W/System.err﹕ subjectAltNames: []
    W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:124)
    W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
    W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
    W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
    W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
    W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
    W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
    W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:273)
    W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:230)
    W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:201)
    W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:81)
    ...
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check that your certificate contains actual host name and not IP address(IP addresses are supposed to be in `Subject Alternative Name` field of certificate). As for `HostnameVerifier` which returns true - it will make SSL useless and insecure(most upvoted answer). On contemporary Androids you can install your self signed certificate without problems via Security settings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally got this working with a mix of multiple answers.

First, the certificates was made wrongly, not sure how. But by creating them using the script in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24749608/964887) made them work. What was needed was a server certificate and a key. Then the client needed another certificate.

To use the certificate in android I converted the .pem file to a .crt file like this:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in client.pem  -out client.crt
```

In android I added the certificate to my OkHttp client like the following:

```
public ApiService() {
    mClient = new OkHttpClient();
    mClient.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mClient.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mClient.setCache(getCache());
    mClient.setSslSocketFactory(getSSL());
}

protected SSLSocketFactory getSSL() {
    try {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream cert = getAppContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client);
        Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(cert);
        cert.close();

        // creating a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        return new AdditionalKeyStore(keyStore);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The last part with `new AdditionalKeyStore()` is taken from [this very well written answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378872/964887). Which adds a fallback keystore.

I hope this might help anyone else! This is the simplest way to get HTTPS working with a self-signed certificate that I have found. Other ways include having a BouncyCastle keystore which seems excessive to me.

Comment: what is the file(client) in raw?

Comment: that is the `client.crt`file generated on the openssl line.

Comment: What is the client.pem file you have used here? That script generate few .pem file. Is it chain.pem file in client directory?

Comment: You have to create it as part of the ssl certificate you want to use for your connection: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32768/converting-keys-between-openssl-and-openssh

Comment: Is is safe to have the .crt file as a raw resource in your apk?

Comment: I have a spring-boot app (version 2.3.7) that uses okhtt3 and I'm trying to call an api in https://test.server.com:8888/api . The certificate on the server is self-signed so I have updated my carets to trust this certificate. When I m running the SSLPoke.class like this `java SSLPoke test.server.com 8888` I m getting Successfully Connected. But when the request is made from my app I m getting the `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname test.server.com not verified:` error. 
Since the cacerts is updated do I need to write extra code to verify the hostname ?

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem, however I needed my application to work on several staging environments, all of which had self signed certs.  To make matters worse, they could change those certs on the fly.

To fix this, when connecting to staging only, I added a SSLSocketFactory which trusted all certs.  This fixed the java error, however it left me with the okhttp exception noted in this ticket.

To avoid this error, I needed to add one more customization to my okHttpClient.  This fixed the error for me.

```
okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is not safe! I know I didn't specify that in my question. I know it works, I have used it earlier. But I'm all grown up now and want the full safety of https. :)

Comment: of course this isn't safe -- this explicitly bypasses https certificate verification.  This should only be used on pre-prod environments where you want to avoid ssl verification, never on a production build.

Comment: `setHostnameVerifier` not compiling

Comment: `setHostnameVerifier()` is not a method of [OkHttpClient](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html). I think you're confusing it with `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`

Comment: thanks. helped me to get rid of error and do my tests on debug

Comment: This is never the way to go, don't pretend a secure connection when it is not, add a big warning!

Answer (score 9):

This issue is solved by setting `setHostNameVerifier` to `okHttpBuilder`. Make sure verify method should return true.

Sample:

```
okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
});

OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });
OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
```

Comment: How safe is this? If it returns true aren't all certificates accepted? If so that should be avoided!

Comment: I agree @just_user. This works, but is not a good solution. Right...?

Comment: @Otziii Yes, this isn't safe. I don't know why people keep suggesting this "solution". Check my answer above, this provides a safer option.

Comment: It helped me so much. Thanks!

Comment: security nightmare, it destroys the security the PKI tries to establish

Answer (score 6):

Please check if CN name on the client cert is added to the Subject alternative name. I had the same issue

Comment: Thank you so much, in particular the Subject alternative name _must_ be set if it is an IP address instead of a hostname: 

"In some cases, the URI is specified as an IP address rather than a
   hostname. In this case, the iPAddress subjectAltName must be present
   in the certificate and must exactly match the IP in the URI." https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2818#section-3.1

Answer (score 5):

During cert generation the `subjectAltName` must be set if the uri is an ip to not fall through validation.

> "In some cases, the URI is specified as an IP address rather than a hostname. In this case, the iPAddress subjectAltName must be present in the certificate and must exactly match the IP in the URI." [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1)  (mentioned by Bas in comment)

Instead of fiddeling client side with `HostnameVerifier` or else, reiusse the self-signed cert (which we have control over) via:

```
openssl req \
-newkey rsa:2048 \
-nodes \
-x509 \
-days 36500 -nodes \
-addext "subjectAltName = IP.1:1.2.3.4" \
-keyout /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned2.key \
-out /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned2.crt
```

Addon, if on android one also needs to trust the cert:

```
the crt is pem format and can be imported into android via
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/nginx_selfsigned2" />
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Thus we verify the cert is from a trusted source And previously by hostname verification (via SAN) ensured the server we talk to presents the right cert for his ip.

more here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#SelfSigned

Answer (score 0):

If you are used `network_security_config` in `res/xml` for solve `Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted` and you changed domain/IP address remember that you should change `includeSubdomains` value to the new address.
This worked for me.

```
  <network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
      <domain includeSubdomains="true">yourDomain.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
  </network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTPS instead of HTTP also causes this error.

When changing your URL to HTTP don't forget to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on `AndroidManifest` file inside `application` tag.