# WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0 Key Manager integration with Keycloak not working

Tags: wso2, keycloak, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have followed this tutorial https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-keycloak-connector/ for integrating Keycloak as Key Manager with WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0 and everything is done as described but when I try to obtain client_credentials access_token an error is rising on WSO2 http client - Keycloak communication, viewing the traces it is related to feign. The error is this:

```
Caused by: feign.RetryableException: Hostname localhost not verified:
    certificate: sha256/7mHCBc7ms9yqA/gz+nIRA9cUTRqrEgK3j9eX9fmpDZ0=
    DN: CN=localhost
    subjectAltNames: [] executing POST https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/master/clients-registrations/openid-connect
```

As it is described on error trace, it is a hostname verification as hostname is localhost. To bypass this I set hostname verification to be disabled, but it is still happening. I do not know how to skip this verification. These are my config files snippets:

**deployment.toml**

```
[transport.passthru_https]
sender.hostname_verifier = "AllowAll"

[transport.passthru_https.sender.parameters]
HostnameVerifier = "AllowAll"

[transport.passthru_http]
sender.hostname_verifier = "AllowAll"
```

**api-manager.bat**

```
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs=%JAVA_ENDORSED% -Dorg.opensaml.httpclient.https.disableHostnameVerification=true -Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier="AllowAll"
```

Also this localhost certificate is imported in client-truststore.jks in WSO2 installation.

Any idea about how to skip this hostname verification?

Comment: Have you tried generating a Self-Signed cert for the Keystore as instructed in the mentioned docs? Or you are using the default cert that is generated by the Keycloak?

Comment: I am using the default cert generated by keycloak in the keystore application.keystore inside standalone folder. In the guide says that you can use that certificate. It is the one I imported in WSO2 client-truststore.jks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 API Manager uses the Feign `OKHTTP` Client to communicate with Keycloak servers. The `OKHTTP` client requires the public cert with `SAN` entries as the same as `CN`.

The default public cert of the Keycloak doesn't contain any `SAN` values. Therefore, when trying to communicate with the Keycloak, the Feign client starts to throw SSL exceptions. To overcome this, you can follow this [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-keycloak-connector/#step-2-configure-wso2-api-manager), creating a new Keystore for the Keycloak and import that cert into the `client-truststore.jks` of the API Manager. The mentioned `keytool` commands generate the Keystore and certs with `SAN` entries.

Given is the same Keytool command from the [API Manager Docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-keycloak-connector/#step-2-configure-wso2-api-manager).

```sh
keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 3650 -keystore application.keystore -dname "CN=localhost,OU=Support,O=WSO2,L=Colombo,S=Western,C=LK" -storepass password -keypass password -noprompt -ext SAN=dns:localhost
```

Further, the mentioned `hostname_verifier` configurations are not applicable to disable the Hostname verification in `OKHTTP` client.

This is not an absolute solution for the behavior that you are facing, but you can go with this alternate approach (generating a new Keystore for the Keycloak) to overcome it.

Few points related to `OKHTTP` client were gathered from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917988/okhttp-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-hostname-domain-com-not-verifie). Hope this helps you to overcome the issue with an alternate approach.

Comment: After creating the certificate with the keytool command you provided it works perfectly. Thank you very much!