# Android studio - No client certificate selected

Tags: android, ssl, build.gradle, stack-overflow, client-certificates

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:aw_contents_client_bridge.cc(255)] No client certificate selected
D/ZIP-Ideation: onPageCommitVisible
D/ZIP-Ideation: onPageCommitVisible
I/X509Util: Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
E/chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
```

I am facing this error in Android studio while running application it is showing blank screen
Please respond if anyone have idea about this error

I have an Android App that needs to connect to a server that has a SSL certificate.

I'm new to this. Can you please tell me the steps to trust that certificate?

I'm using Gradle project

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71530525/150978