https problem with Android application local testing
I'm trying to test my android app locally.
The app has to fetch data from 192.168.1.16.
The local server certificate is a self signed certificate, so I did what I found here and there on stackoverflow and other sites (special thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542188/3872061):
. stored the certificate in res/raw/laragon_certif
. created a res/xml/network_security_config.xml pointing to the @raw/laragon_certif
. added attribute android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" on node application in manifest.xml
Now all previous errors and exceptions changed to the following:
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 192.168.1.16 not verified:
    certificate: sha1/Gr8h0ea/mhIMIADb7CMK47K8Moo=
    DN: CN=laragon,OU=IT,O=Laragon,L=Singapore,ST=Singapore,C=SG
    subjectAltNames: [localhost, ..., ..., ..., 192.168.1.16]

So it seems the app correctly finds the self-signed certificate and does not reject it any more, but it doesn't consider 192.168.1.16 to be covered by this certificate.

I just figured out that an IP should be declared as IP.1=192.168.1.16 and not DNS.7=192.168.1.16 in openssl conf when creating certificate. Now the exception changed to something about "key usage"

After searching for hours, I finally got it to work minutes after asking...
Still posting an answer rather than deleting my question as I might not be the only one having this issue.

all steps here were a good start, this was more than half of the answer to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542188/3872061

I needed to add my local IP to the servers covered by the certificate:
simply a new IP.1=192.168.1.16 entry in the subjectAltNamesection of openssl.conf

then as an answer to the key usage related exception, I compared the key usages of stackoverflow's certificate with the key usages of my self signed certificate and saw that mine had neither digitalSignature nor clientAuth. I added both and now I get no more exception when trying to reach my local server from within the application.


side note : the local server is Laragon-driven. For those using it, some precisions:
Laragon makes its own self signed certificate into etc/ssl . In order to change certificate settings, I had to:
. modify etc/ssl/openssl.conf of course
. make this file readonly to prevent Laragon from overwriting it when creating its certificate
. then disable and re-enable https from within Laragon's panel. This will trigger a new self signed certificate creation.
