# Solving Nodejs https.request self-signed certificate error in production

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, nginx, self-signed

I am using Nodejs/Express along with nginx. I am trying to make https.request from an Express route which results in self signed certificate error. I have resolved the error in development mode using:

> process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"

which worked perfectly. I will be deploying my application on CentOS. My question is how to avoid the same error in production mode. Nginx is being used on CentOS too. I tried creating the certificate on CentOS based on [How To Create a SSL Certificate on nginx for CentOS 6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-centos-6)

But, that doesn't solve the purpose as the Node application can be running on any CentOS VM and I don't want to perform these steps for each virtual machine. Is there anything which I can do from the application side to avoid this error in production?

Some of the similar questions that I already went through on StackOverflow are:

- [create a trusted self-signed SSL cert for localhost (for use with Express/Node)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397809/create-a-trusted-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-localhost-for-use-with-express-node)
- [How do I use a self signed certificate for a HTTPS Node.js server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665863/how-do-i-use-a-self-signed-certificate-for-a-https-node-js-server)
- [How can I create a self-signed cert for localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169999/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-cert-for-localhost?noredirect=1&lq=1)