# Handshake failure in ExpressJS Node app with Let's Encrypt SSL certificates

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm having an issue setting up a node server with let's encrypt certificates. I'm using Express to create https server like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var app = require('express')();
var https = require('https');

var server = https.createServer({ 
key: 
fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem'), 
cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem'), 
ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/chain.pem'), 
requestCert: true, 
rejectUnauthorized: true},app);

app.get("/express", function(request, response){
response.end("Express Response");
});
server.listen(8082);
```

I want to set **rejectUnauthorized: true** because I've read that disabling it makes the client/server communication vulnerable to MITM attack. For the client side i'm using the **request** module to make the https GET request like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var requests = require('request');
var fileSystem = require('fs');

var checkRequestOpts = {
    url: "https://example.com:8082/express",
    agentOtions: {
        ca: fileSystem.readFileSync(__dirname + '/chain1.pem')
    },
    method: 'GET',
    json: true,
    formData: {
        'x': 100,
        'y': 500,
        'z': 97    
    }
};

requests(checkRequestOpts, function(err, sr, rb)
{
    if(err)
        console.log('Error occured' + err);
    else
    {
        console.log('Response: ' + rb);
    }
});
```

However, when I run the client side app it crashes with error

```
Error occuredError: write EPROTO 140593052855168:error:14094410:SSL 
routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake 
failure:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1399:SSL alert number 40
```

The server does not have to provide content to a broswer it just needs to work with the client node app. It works when I set **rejectUnauthorized: false** but not when it is set to true.
I'd be really thankful if someone could help me out on this or give any leads to a possible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The naming isn't what you think it is.

Essentially, you've mixed up `ca`, `cert`, and `key`, which is a very common mistake.

Here's a few resources to take a look at:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-root-cas
- [How do I use a self signed certificate for a HTTPS Node.js server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665863/how-do-i-use-a-self-signed-certificate-for-a-https-node-js-server)
- https://coolaj86.com/articles/create-your-own-certificate-authority-for-testing/

## Solution

- `key` refers to `privkey.pem`
- `cert` refers to the **concatenation** of `cert.pem` AND `chain.pem` (aka `fullchain.pem`)

You should ignore `ca` because `ca` refers to Certificate Authority and is where you would put `root.pem` if you were using enterprise or military peer certificate validation.

- `rejectUnauthorized: true` IS disabling the security checks. You DO NOT want this. You want `rejectUnauthorized: false` (the default).
- `requestCert: true` is only used for peer-certificate validation. You DO NOT want this.

  - See https://github.com/coolaj86/nodejs-ssl-trusted-peer-example for more explanation

## Try Greenlock Too

Also, you might prefer to use [greenlock-express.js](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/greenlock-express.js) (Let's Encrypt / ACME client for node.js/express.js) so that you don't have to do any manual work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should set client's cert if you use self-signed SSL certificates. It is not required to set this when use Let's Encrypt certificates, it has already stored in your browser or system.